# select dropdown/flatten observable

Tags: angular, rxjs6

This is a two-part question. With Angular 6, I'm returning an observable with a nested collection. I need the nested collection to serve as the selected values in a reactive forms multiple select list. 1) Using patchValue, I can't get the values to show as selected items. 2) How do I flatten the observable, or push the nested collection into the control?

**HTML**:

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select [compareWith]="compareFn" placeholder="Menus" formArrayName="menus" multiple >
<mat-option *ngFor="let menu of menus" [value]="menu">{{menu.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**menuItem Class**:

```
id: string
name: string
menus: [id: string, name: string]
```

...'menus' is the nested collection which holds the id and name of the menus to which this menuItem is assigned.

**API call**:

```
getMenuItem(id: string) : Observable<MenuItem>{
    return this.http.get<MenuItem>(`${this.URL}/${id}`)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError<MenuItem>('getMenuItem')));}
```

**Component**

Relevants parts of the component:

```
createForm(){
this.menuItemForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  itemName: ['', Validators.required ],
  itemDescription: ['', Validators.required ],
  active: true,
  menus: this.menus
})
```

'this.menus' is the select list of all menus

**Subscription**

```
getMenuItem(id: string){
this.menuItemService.getMenuItem(id)
  .subscribe(
  (data: MenuItem) => this.onItemRetrieved(data),
  (err: any) => console.log(err));}
```

I think this is where I need to flatten the observable in order to take the nested collection out of being nested, but I'm not sure how to do it and still retain my class definition.

**OnItemRetrieved**

```
onItemRetrieved(menuItem: MenuItem): void {
if (this.menuItemForm){
  this.menuItemForm.reset();
}

this.menuItem = menuItem;

this.menuItemForm.patchValue({
  ...
  menus: this.menuItem.menus      

});
```

Nothing I've tried is getting the values in this.menuItem.menus to show as selected in my select list. In the sample data, I have one menu(id/name) and I've tried this.menuItem.menus[0], and that doesn't work either, which is why I have two problems. :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you share the response you are getting back?

Comment: The response from the api is:

    `{
    "itemname": "Carne Asada",

    "itemdescription": "A tender skirt...",

    "active": true,



    "menus": [{
 "id": "AllDayDining",
 "name": "All Day Dining"
        }
    ],
 
    "id": "CarneAsada::79b0c6ab-f93b-438f-93fb-2a6272f561c6"}`

Comment: I couldn't get the material controls working properly so I created a stackblitz with regular ones. You can see the select control still doesn't show the proper menu selected.

https://angular-s5u4hr.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Problem solved. When experimenting/debugging the select, I changed the formControlName to formControlArray and forgot to change it back. Thanks for your help Vikas.

Comment: Cool you figured out the solution:)